# Simplebar-vue doesn't work inside a modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on small project Using Vuejs and i have installe simplebar-vue it work fine but not inside a modal.

this is my code :

```
<b-modal v-model="showRightBar" title="Add Contact" modal-class="right">
        <simplebar class="h-100">
          <div style="height:500px;">hello</div>
        </simplebar>
</b-modal>
```

This is my custom css for the modal also :

```
    .modal.right .modal-dialog {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    width: 420px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}
.modal.right .modal-content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.modal.right .modal-body {
    padding: 15px 15px 80px;
}   
/*Right*/
.modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.right.fade.in .modal-dialog {
    right: 0;
}

/* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
.modal-content {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
}

.modal-header {
    border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

**issue is : i don't see the scrolling bar**

By the way simplebar works fine outside of the modal. (bootstrap-vue)
Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Modal appended to body element when opened and removed when closed. So there is a need to use create Simplebar instance when modal will be shown.

```
<b-modal v-model="showRightBar" title="Add Contact" modal-class="right" @shown="handleShown">
    <simplebar ref="simplebar" class="h-100">
        <div style="height:500px;">hello</div>
    </simplebar>
</b-modal>
```

Use @shown handler on b-modal. https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#comp-ref-b-modal-events

```
handleShown() {
   new SimpleBar(this.$refs.simplebar)
}
```

Working example on codepen: https://codepen.io/corresponding/pen/xxYQQVJ